# Python - Extracting a character from an integer

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an algorithm in python that asks you to insert a number and then it prints the hundreds, dozens and units from the number inserted.

What I was thinking to do is to extract the character from the number that corresponds to the hundreds and print it as hundreds, as well with the dozens and units.

For instance, what I've tried to do so far was:

```
number = 321 
print 'Hundreds: ', number[1]
```

However, when I tried to run that, I got the message:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Is it impossible to do what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `str(number)[1]`. You first have to convert the number to a string.

Note that this is not the most elegant solution. You might want to try `(number // 100)%10` instead. Therefore, `number` has to be an `int`. The `//` denotes integer division.

Comment: Integer division is the best solution.  For the hundreds though, divide by 100 and then mod 10 (your code gets the 10s place).  This will work in Python 2.x only.  In 3.x, division is floating point.  *edit:* to make it forward compatible, use the `//` operator for division instead of `/`.

Comment: Humm... That worked!!
I'm gonna try both ways, though. See wich one is better.
Thaks for the help!! XD

Comment: @ThiG. I suppose both work, but usually the way without string conversion should be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
number = 321
```

to

```
number = str(321)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make it a string first, try...

`str(number)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Try `print 'Hundreds:', str(number)[-3] if number >= 100 else '0'`

Comment: To get the hundreds it should be `str(number)[0]`.

Comment: @RikPoggi: True. I just carried over the same error from the question, I guess. Actually using `str(number)[-3]` might be better if you don't know how many digits are in the number (checking the length to make sure there are at least three, of course).

Comment: (+1) Right, that's even better!

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the integer into a string before:

```
number = 321
s = str(number)
hundreds = s[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print 'Hundereds: ', str(number // 100)[-1]
print 'Tens: ', str(number // 10)[-1]
print 'Ones: ', str(number)[-1]
```